# Insert or update scala dataframe in postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, amazon-rds, slick

I have a look up table that needs to be updated from my spark code. There are multiple spark jobs using the same look up table.

I have a dataframe that needs to be inserted or updated into Postgres table. I cant do it using sparks native postgres library because it only supports appends and overwrites, however I have a clear case of insert or update.

Things i have tried

1. I have tried using slick but am unable to get anything working and the documentation seemed confusing.
2. I also tried using foreach partition and iterating on every row and running the query using slicks db.run functionality, still not working and no errors

The thing is I'm unable to get a working solution, can someone share their code snippet on how they got it to be working? Seems like a pretty common use case but Im stuck.

Comment: Did you try `UPSERT` with `foreach, foreachPartition` with standard JDBC connection?

Comment: can you add the code you use with the foreachPartition case?

Comment: Just union with existing data you don't want to change, and overwrite.